# CMake build failed with error 'SecTrustEvaluateAsync' undeclared when using gcc 5.3 on OS X

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build CMake 3.5.2 from source on Mac El Captain using GNU GCC 5.3 from HPC. 
The `./bootstrap` process is completed successfully but when i am using `make` is failing with the following error.

```
/Users/dev/Downloads/CMake-master/Utilities/cmcurl/lib/vtls/darwinssl.c: In function ‘darwinssl_connect_step3’:
/Users/dev/Downloads/CMake-master/Utilities/cmcurl/lib/vtls/darwinssl.c:1999:6: error: ‘SecTrustEvaluateAsync’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if(SecTrustEvaluateAsync != NULL) {
      ^
/Users/dev/Downloads/CMake-master/Utilities/cmcurl/lib/vtls/darwinssl.c:1999:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: *** [Utilities/cmcurl/lib/CMakeFiles/cmcurl.dir/vtls/darwinssl.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Utilities/cmcurl/lib/CMakeFiles/cmcurl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The same process worked fine when I was using the default clang compiler provided with Mac OS.

When I tried finding about SecTrustEvaluateAsync I found the following information in the [apple site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecTrustEvaluateAsync).

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I have this exact problem as well. I did find this (https://github.com/hashdist/hashstack/issues/746), but I can't figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: I have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

You might try the latest CMake 3.6-rc1. If the problem persists, file a bug to notice the CMake developers. We probably won't fix CMake's code.